# artifacts for pages are too large in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-pages, gitlab-pipelines

I am trying to enable gitlab pages with 100 MB size, but pages:deploy job is failing with error message of " pages:deploy - artifacts for pages are too large.

I have increased pages artifact size to 2048 MB in admin > settings > preferences > pages and increased job artifact size as well, but still getting same error.

any suggestions!!

Comment: Just to make sure, you followed these instructions? https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/pages/#set-global-maximum-pages-size-per-project